# Not able to render/retain graph on button click HighChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to plot a graph on click of a button. In my code below when I click on button 'click me' I am able to see graph displaying on my screen but it quickly disappers from screen. I thing the graph is not being rendered. I am not sure where am I going wrong. I need the graph to persist on my screen. I shall be populating the values for data and categories dynamically once I get this issue solved.

I need to call jquery function from javascript function only due to structure of my exisiting code.

Can anyone please let me know why the graph is not just persisted or retained on screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>
  </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var data= new Array();
var categories= new Array();
function test()
{
       data=[{
                name: 'Part A',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, null, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'Prat B',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, null, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Part C',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'Part D',
                data: [null, 4.2, 5.7, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 6.6, 4.8]
            }];

         categories=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];                      
    }
    function my_met(){ 
           alert("hey");               
            $('#container').highcharts({             
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'area',
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: data
        })      
    }        
//just js 
function js_fun () {  
    test();
   my_met(); //== call jquery function - just Reference is globally defined not function itself
}   
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
</div>    
<div id="city_form">
  <form name="contact" action="" method="post">
      <button id="control" onclick="js_fun()">Click me</button> 
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only persists for a short time because you have placed your `button` within a `form` here:

```
<form name="contact" action="" method="post">
    <button id="control" onclick="js_fun()">Click me</button> 
</form>
```

When clicking the button the form is submitted. Since `action=""` it submits the form to the same page, and you once again have to call `js_fun()` to render the graph. The graph is only shown the short time between clicking the button and the new page being loaded.

You could make your button code like this:

```
    <button id="control" onclick="js_fun(); return false">Click me</button>
```

Or just remove the `form` tag if you're not actually planing on submitting a form at any time.

Answer (score 1):

If you does not give any type for the button tag element, it will point as submit. when you click the button, the form is submitted first after that only JavaScript calls.You did not mention any action for the form tag, so form is submitted to the same page.So button JavaScript click event does not call because the page is refreshed each button click.

You have 3 ways to resolved this type issues

1.If you does not post any form values then remove the form tag, just put only the button tag.

2.include the return false in the button on-click event.

```
     <button id="control" onclick="js_fun(); return false">Click me</button>
```

3.Include button type="button" in the button tag element.

```
      <button id="control" type="button" onclick="js_fun();">Click me</button>
```